# What is the difference between using SDL_Surface and SDL_Texture to display images?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I just moved on to SDL2 from SDL 1.2 and I see that they have a `SDL_Texture` struct. Whats the difference between using `SDL_Surface` and `SDL_BlitSurface()` and using an `SDL_Texture` and `SDL_Renderer()`.

Comment: Did you check for any notes on the documentation?